# having a global variable persist after crashes in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

So lets say I have this global variable `foo`, which while my server is running I can access it. What I want to be possible is if my server crashes it will first initially try to recover `foo`, then continue to do server stuff. I want to know the best way possible to do such a thing. Here are the ways I can think of doing this.

1, Whenever `foo` is updated, (which not frequently), I will write to a file a marshalized `foo`, and when my server crashes it will `eval` the content's of the file to be `foo`.

2, Use a light database such as sqlite to store `foo`,

Come to think about it both these ideas are really closely related, but is there a referred solution given that `foo` is at any point going to be `10kBytes`.

Comment: What is your specific question?  Yes, these are both feasible ways of accomplishing your task (de/serializing data to/from a global variable); there are likely others and each has its pros and cons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the var in redis. This allows what you want and provides scalability.

Node redis module: https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

Hands on: http://howtonode.org/node-redis-fun